# RecyclerView scroll by page

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of elements in a size-constrained container, and I'm trying to understand the best way to "scroll" the elements in the container by "page". In other words, I don't want smooth scrolling but rather a "page up" / "page down" sort of behavior.

The complexity is that the elements are not a fixed size so I can't just say render the first N elements, then on scroll, render the next N, etc.

As far as I can tell `RecyclerView` et. al. does not provide any support for this behavior, but it seems like a common UX pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe try using view pager.

Comment: Try using [viewpager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2)  it uses the recycler adapter so you don't need to re-code the entire process and can easily modify it to provide page up/ page down behavior

Answer (score 1):

I think SnapHelper can help you. try this :

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView);
```

or if you want your recycler view to react like a view pager you can use this :

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView);
```

Comment: Snap helper snaps to individual elements, not pages (or groups of elements).